# SQL Server fails with stack overflow on simple query

Tags: sql-server

"The query processor ran out of stack space during query optimization."

```
errorCode=8621 sqlState=S0001
query :
DELETE FROM SOMETABLE WHERE somecolumn is null
```

it fails with error above, i googled for solution, but only find many people having such problem with table with large amount of foreign keys, this table having only 180 external and 5 internal. Another point about this table - it has two self-references. I mean two foreign keys that point on table itself, can it be cause of problem?
I having this problem on customer PC with:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (RTM) - 10.0.1600.22 (X64)
```

But on my PC the same query on same table works fine, my version :

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP2) - 10.50.4042.0 (X64)
```

Comment: 'Only 180'. Only 180 foreign keys?! In what way is 180 foreign keys a small number?

Comment: Your customer needs to upgrade their SQL Server to 2008 SP4.

Comment: Google gives me threads where people having this problem and talking about more than 250 fk. Once i seen, that this problem was solved by decreasing number of fk's to 200. And, anyway, i think it's not so big number for enterprise app.

Comment: @MarkSinkinson is there a way to go through this problem without update?

Comment: It might be a bug that has been fixed in later versions (seeing as you're not having the issue yourself on 2008 R2 SP2). Your customer is running an RTM, so any bugs discovered in the 7 years between August 7th 2008 and today are unfixed.

Comment: Install an instance of Microsoft SQL Server 2008 RTM on your pc and try it. If it fails, then update to SP1, test it again and then SP2, SP3, SP4 until you figure out which SP must be installed

Comment: Or just install SP4; why bother with earlier service packs with fewer fixes?

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand Yes, but if in this situation, I would also want to know which one is causing/solving the problem.

Comment: @Julien why does it matter which one solves the problem? I don't see any advantage to going with the bare minimum service pack vs. the latest with the most fixes, so knowing SP1 or SP2 fixes it, who cares?

Comment: Manager who knows nothing, trust no one and will not agree on a single update from RTM to SP4 because he thinks this is a bigger risk or at least will want to know which one fixes it. This scenario is not uncommum with SQL Server or any software.